# IPv6 fragmentation not happening

Tags: ip, ipv6, mtu

I have set up a test network with 2 Linux PCs working as routers and 2 Linux PCs working as normal clients. The 2 routers are connected to each other and each client is connected to one router. On the path from the client to one of the routers the MTU is 1500, however between the two routers it is 1200. Also I am using IPv6 only.

If I now try to send a packet which is bigger than 1200 bytes I expect to get a ICMPv6 "packet too big" error from the router and the client should then fragment the packet and attempt to resend it. However this does not happen. If I look at wireshark i can see the client receiving the ICMPv6 errors, however the client does not attempt to resend the packages as fragments.

What could be the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IPsec tunnel MTU too small](https://superuser.com/questions/1312594/ipsec-tunnel-mtu-too-small)

Comment: Some (bad) filtering on the client side that filters out ICMP packets?

Comment: See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8201 and specifically: "Nodes implementing Path MTU Discovery and sending packets larger than
   the IPv6 minimum link MTU are susceptible to problematic connectivity
   if ICMPv6 [ICMPv6] messages are blocked or not transmitted.  For
   example, this will result in connections that complete the TCP three-
   way handshake correctly but then hang when data is transferred.  This
   state is referred to as a black-hole connection [RFC2923].  Path MTU
   Discovery relies on ICMPv6 Packet Too Big (PTB) to determine the MTU
   of the path."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPv6 doesn't support fragmentation.

With IPv4, a router may fragment a packet when forwarding from one link to another link with a smaller MTU (unless *DF* is set).

With IPv6, the endpoints need to use *Path MTU Discovery* to actually find it out by themselves and then use this MTU between themselves...

**Edit** after @Patrick Mevzek's greatly appreciated comments:

... or resort to use the guaranteed MTU for IPv6 of 1280 bytes (with or without fragmenting the packet on the host).

Comment: Routers do not fragment, but hosts can. See RFC8200 point 5: "It is strongly recommended that IPv6 nodes implement Path MTU
   Discovery [RFC8201], in order to discover and take advantage of path
   MTUs greater than 1280 octets.  However, a minimal IPv6
   implementation (e.g., in a boot ROM) may simply restrict itself to
   sending packets no larger than 1280 octets, and omit implementation of Path MTU Discovery." PMTUD is strongly recommended, not mandatory. End nodes can use IPv6 Fragment Header to send packets bigger than the path's MTU.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - I wouldn't call that fragmentation though: the v6 header has no provision for fragmentation and the 'minimal' client just uses a quaranteed-to-work MTU.

Comment: It is called the IPv6 Fragment Header... if that is not fragmentation, I do not know what it is. There is no "v6 header", in IPv6 headers form a chain, based on the features needed.

Comment: Seems I've missed that - thanks again. I have yet to see this in real life but I'm prepared now.